# Hide or show element of a component based on role permission in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, higher-order-components

I want to show/hide element present in a component, based on role level permission,
here is the code which I tried so far

My Component:

```
   <ShowForPermission permission="My Studies" configuration={configuration}>
  <div>Mystudies</div>
   <ShowForPermission>
```

HOC:

```
import React from 'react'

export const ShowForPermission = ({ permission, configuration}) => {

    
    const isAllowed = checkPermission(permission, configuration);

     return isAllowed
     
    
  }

  export const checkPermission = (permission, configuration) => {
   
    return configuration&&configuration.filter((item)=>item.name===permission)[0].permission.read
}
```

Here in My Component I'm passing key as **My Studies** and role config of that particular component as **configuration** to **ShowForPermission**
And in HOC I'm checking the given key i.e permission "My studies" equals to `configuration.filter((item)=>item.name==="My Studies")` so what I'm checking s suppose if this value is true I want render div present in my Component or else no. How to achieve this. Please help me on this

`if permission.read==true, return true else false` and render div based on condition.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you've described is not a HOC. That's fine, component composition(when you nest component to show in another component that provides control) suits even better than HOC here.

So your `ShowForPermission` makes some check and renders whatever nested component provided(nested components are passed as [`children` prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#props))

```
export const ShowForPermission = ({ permission, children }) => {
  const isAllowed = ..... // do some permission check
  if (isAllowed) {
    return children; // rendering nested elements
  } else {
    /*
     it also might be false, empty string or empty array
     (and for React 18 it can be `return;` or `return undefined` as well);
     also you even can omit explicit `return undefined;` for `else` branch
     but this way intention is more clear
    */
    return null; 
  }
}
```

But how do you get `configuration`? Definitely not passing it as a prop. Why? Because you will need to pass it every time you use `ShowForPermission`. And to pass it in 3rd-, 5th- or 10th-level nested component you would have to pass `configuration` to every its parent up the line. That has name of "prop drilling" and [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) is exactly what been created to solve this.

Context API is a way to inject data into component without passing it explicitly into every parent as a prop. Take a look into examples in docs, finally your app should load configuration and create `<YourContextProvider value={configurationData}>` somewhere at the very root app element or close to the root. I'm intentionally skip question how you can load that configuration before passing to context(a large separate topic and also it's up to your requirements).

Finally, your `ShowForPermission` would access data from context(preferably with `useContext` hook) to check the permission:

```
export const ShowForPermission = ({ permission, children }) => {
  const configuration = useContext(YourPermissionContext);
  const isAllowed = configuration
    .filter(
      (item) => item.name===permission
    )[0].permission.read;

  if (isAllowed) {
    return children; // rendering nested elements
  } else {
    return null; 
  }
}
```